# Simply adding two macro variables in SAS

Tags: macros, sas

I'm currently trying to simply add two macros being created. But I'm struggling quite badly with this. It seemed very straight forward at the beginning but..
So here is what I'm trying to do..

```
%let A = 5;
%let B = 10;

%let AB = &A + &B;
%put &AB;
```

Rather than giving me 15 which is what I want, SAS spits out 5 + 10

Help anyone..??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Small terminology comment, you’re adding macro variables not macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are floating point then use `%sysevalf()`:

```
%let AB = %sysevalf(&a + &b);
```